# c# how update datagridview changes when data adpreter is in antoher project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 projects in solution

1. Data
2. Bussnies
3. Presentation (win forms)

In presentation i have `DataGridView` where i show data from `Data` layer. In data layer i have repository classes for returning data from database.

My question is next:

To save all changes i need access to Adapter but my adapter is stored in Data layer. In presentation i get Bussniess instance and get database records from bussnes layer.

**Method from data:**

```
  public DataSet GetAll()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(DB.ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Subjekti_Tip_List";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

**Bussnies:**

```
  public DataSet GetAll()
    {
        return reposotory.GetAll();
    }
```

**Presentation**

```
void Table_RowChanged
  (object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
    {
    TableAdapter.Update(e.Row);  // HERE I NEED INSTANCE OF ADAPTER FROM DATA LAYER 
  }
}
```

So here is problem i want update changes and save it to database. In Presentation layer i dont have access to adapter how can i do this to be good and maintnanced.

Comment: add business project as reference then try.

Comment: That should be a BLL method. Just like the `GetAll()`. Imitate this method to create a BLL & DAL methods for the update part.

Comment: @dr.null thanks for answer. Did you mean i need to create new method in BLL which will contain Adapter instance or what? Show me samthing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two code snippets are textbook implementation of the *3-tier architecture* design. But, you broke that in the last code snippet. The front-end/presentation/UI layer (name it) should never takeover the DAL's role and deal directly with the back-end/DB. As I commented, you need to preserve the design and *imitate* the first two code snippets for the Update/Delete/Insert/Count/Sum ...etc. routines. For example, let's highlight the *Update* part.

**DAL**

---

Add `Update` method to be called by the BLL. You can add more overloads to pass different data objects and call the proper [`Update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/Overload_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter_Update.htm) overload. Please note, the DAL is the only place in this design for data objects like connections, commands, adapters, transactions, command builders.

```cs
public void Update(DataTable dt)
{
    // The update routine. Here is where you should use the data adapter...
}

public void Update(DataSet ds)
{
    // ...
}

public void Update(DataRow[] rows)
{
    // ...
}
```

**BLL - The Agent**

---

Add BLL methods, called by the presentation layer. You can add routines here to validate the inputs, throw exception for null/invalid arguments ...etc.

```cs
public void Update(DataTable dt)
{
    // Validate, throw or proceed...

    reposotory.Update(dt);
}

public void Update(DataSet ds)
{
    reposotory.Update(ds);
}

public void Update(DataRow[] rows)
{
    reposotory.Update(rows);
}
```

**UIL**

---

In your front-end, I presume you have a reference to the BLL project and instance of it. Let's name it `MyBLL`.

```cs
void Caller()
{
    // Update a DataSet...
    MyBLL.Update(yourDataSetIfAny);
    yourDataSetIfAny.AcceptChanges(); // Only when you get a successful update.

    // OR
    DataTable dt = // Get the DataTable..
    MyBLL.Update(dt);
    dt.AcceptChanges(); // On a successful update.
    
    // OR
    MyBLL.Update(dt.GetChanges()); // See the GetChanges overloads..
    dt.AcceptChanges();    

    // OR
    MyBLL.Update(dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x => x.RowState == DataRowState.Modified).ToArray());
    // DO NOT call dt.AcceptChanges(); here if the dt still contains deleted or new rows.
}
```